# TestDriven.NET is not running my SetUp methods for MbUnit

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tdd, mbunit, testdriven.net

I've created some MbUnit Test Fixtures that have SetUp methods marked with the SetUp attribute.  These methods run before the tests just fine using the MbUnit GUI, the console runner, and the ReSharper MbUnit plugin.  However, when I run the tests with TestDriven.NET it does not run the SetUp methods at all.

Does anyone know if this is a bug with TestDriven.NET or if I have something setup wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No longer an issue with recent versions of Gallio since v3.0.4.  Just make sure to use the 64-bit installer.

Comment: Yep.  I'm using that now, and I've been happy.

Answer (score 2):

After having this problem for weeks on Vista 64, I found a [post](http://blog.davebouwman.com/2008/08/06/trouble-running-mbunit-tests-with-testdriven-net-on-vista-64/) by Dave Bouwman just today, and it fixed this problem.

Comment: Link is broken now. 404 File not found.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue after installing NUnit using nuget ... previously I had been using an older version of NUnit and everything had worked fine.

I think TestDriven is not compatible with the latest version of NUnit.

I've switched to using NCrunch, which is free, and compiles/runs tests in the backgound as you are coding, amongst other things. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue with NUnit and TestDriven.NET that took me hours to figure out.
I installed the Visual Studio Extension below and it hit breakpoint in the Tests but skipped the one in the one in the [TestFixtureSetUp].

[image]

It turned out that I also needed the actual TestDriven.NET software to be installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\TestDriven.NET 4

This is available from https://www.testdriven.net/download.aspx