# TestDriven.net with Gallio, MbUnit and NCover problems

Tags: mbunit, gallio, testdriven.net, ncover

Why doesnt TestDriven.Net work with my gallio/mbunit tests?

I've used TDD.Net with MbUnit v2 and not had any problems, but with the new gallio release on my new pc, it does nothing.

From the tdd right click menu in solution explorer, if i do "test with debugger" i get "0 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped" in the VS status bar at the bottom of the screen.

If i right click my fixture and do the same, i get

```
"The target type doesn't contain tests from a known test framework or a 'Main' method."
```

If i do it on an individual test, it looks like its not running the SetUp, so the test fails (but at least it runs)

I know this sounds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984/testdrivennet-is-not-running-my-setup-methods-for-mbunit) problem, but my registry looks correct.

If i try and run NCover from the TDD.Net menu, nothing happens (other than an an output window flicker)

When i do "run unit tests" with resharper it picks them all up and runs correctly.

Im using Gallio/MbUnit 3.0.5.546, TDD.Net 2.18.2268, Resharper 4.1, VS 2k8 Pro 9.0.30729.1 SP, .Net 3.5 SP1, Windows Server 2k8 (x86)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to make sure you install TestDriven.Net before Gallio.  Otherwise the Gallio installer will not install its extensions for TestDriven.Net.

Comment: Yeah thats what i found, +1 for writing it down!

Comment: I installed TestDriven.NET before installing Gallio and the tests are still not recognized.

Answer (score 3):

Also check that you are not throwing an exception in your fixture setup.  This results in *exactly* the same error message.

See the 'Test Report' hyperlink just before the error message for further details (I usually ignore this link!)

Comment: will try this, ta for the tip

Comment: I wasn't getting a link in my output, but did find an exception occurring in the setup, so this helped me; thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of uninstalling, rebooting and reinstalling seems to have solved it :s

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when my test specification class was in a project other than the tests project/namespace.